# Авторизация в панелеи администратора, php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Как можно сделать ограничение доступа к странице другим пользователям и сделать проверку на администратора с помощью PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Если у вас пользователи имеют доступ к базе, то какая разница, через какой-интерфейс они этот доступ получат?

Comment: @teran господи, да базу данных он свою так называет. У них у всех же БД называется "PhpMyAdmin". Вопрос про банальную авторизацию на сайте. Вчера, кстати, уже задавал, так же невнятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте в БД отношение id, username, password

в html форму для отправки логина/пароля

в php проверку на наличие введенных в форму данных в Вашей БД и выдачу HTML страницы, если пользователь найден

Это элементарная авторизация. В Google полно информации, как это сделать.
И почитайте про сессии

PhpMyAdmin тут совершенно не причем. Это всего лишь инструмент для работы с БД